# How do I make drastic changes to a git repository without having to start over?

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I've got a problem with one of my git repositories (FYI: I'm *really* new to git)

Basically I forgot about the repo I'd created for a project, worked on the wrong set of files (my original copies), made some BIG changes and renamed most of the files.

Now I've realised my mistake I was wondering how I can put the new files in to my repo, replacing the old files so that I don't end up with 2 different versions of the same files under 2 different names.

I didn't want to have to completely delete the old repo and re-create it again with the new files because I've already pushed it up to github.

Anyone able to offer some help and/or advice please?

nb: wasn't sure of the best 'Stack' site to put this on, figured here or programming?!

Comment: thanks grawity - yeh i wasn't sure where best to put this question. happy for it to be flagged to be moved though if needs be? I'll probably give your solution a go though. I've only created the repo a couple of days ago and I'm  the only developer so I doubt anyone else is using it. thanks

Comment: Have all the renames been done with `git mv`? If they're all tracked changes, what's preventing you from pushing it?

Comment: Just because got is mainly used by programmers does not mean it is off topic here.  This is a usage question for git and if it can be answered here it can stay here, though be aware it *may* be answered quicker on SO.

Comment: Thanks @Christopher this is probably how I should (and from now on will) have done it -- i.e. rename all the old files as 'tracked changes' then just copy the new files over the top, commit and push.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have a repository R and a different working directory W, on which you have worked without having any version control, right?

Basically, after you made sure there are no uncommited changes in R, you replace the checkout of R with the content of W: Delete the content of R, except for the .git directory and any .git* files, and copy the content of W into it, so that the files that stayed the same are on their old places.

Then you create a new commit and push it up to github.

Comment: Thanks @Ozan this is what I did and it worked great! I realize that my question is perhaps a bit of a non-issue in the end, but as I said I'm still learning to use git (and version control in general) properly.